# Why is IISExpress giving me a 404 when clearly file is present?

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

I have a path C:\development\app with a simple file 'release-notes.html'.

I've started IISExpress in the same path like so:

```
C:\development\app\iisexpress /port:8080 /path:.
```

Yet when I browse to the release-notes.html file, I am getting a 404 error.

I can see IISExpress has started ok so why would I get a 404 error when the file is present?

Comment: I am now trying this on a machine at work and the error is a status 500. Is there any way to find out what is causing the error?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. I can navigate to http://localhost:8080/release-notes.html without errors. Have you listed all your steps?

Comment: What if you use the full physical path of the site, instead of `.` in the `/path:` switch?

Comment: The full path seems to work ok. Thanks!

Comment: If you add the answer I can mark it as answered...